# xml export php code returns only one parent of the xml file i need them all

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach, nodes

```
    $rss_tags = array(
    'drawNo',
    'drawTime',
    'result',
    );
  $rss_item_tag = 'draw';
  $rss_url = "http://applications.opap.gr/DrawsRestServices/kino/drawDate/21-12-2014.xml";

  $rssfeed = rss_to_array($rss_item_tag,$rss_tags,$rss_url);


  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($rssfeed);

/*$total=1;
  foreach($rssfeed as $item)
        {
          if($total<750){
          echo '<div><h1>Κλήρωση: '.$item['drawNo']. '  Αριθμοί: ' .$item['result'].'</h1></div>';
          $total++;
          }
        }
*/

  function rss_to_array($tag, $array, $url) {
    $doc = new DOMdocument();
    $doc->load($url);
    $rss_array = array();
    $items = array();
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName($tag) AS $node) { //se auth thn epanalhpsh epanalamvenete toses fores oses oi klhrwseis tis hmeras
      foreach($array AS $key => $value) { //$array einai ta rss tags
          if($value=="result"){
            for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){$items["result"] = $node->getElementsByTagName("result")->item(0)->nodeValue;}
          }
          $items[$value] = $node->getElementsByTagName($value)->item(0)->nodeValue;

      }
      array_push($rss_array, $items);
    }
    return $rss_array;
  }
```

Hello phpers, this is my code to read some xml information but i have a big big big problem.

Firstly check the xml source:
http://applications.opap.gr/DrawsRestServices/kino/drawDate/21-12-2014.xml

The structure is like that:

```
<draws>
  <draw>
     <drawNo>
     <drawTime>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
     <result>
```

and my code returns only the first entry of the  but i want to get both 20 entries could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly do you want to output, but maybe this will suit your purpose.

The code below converts xml to array.

```
<?php
$xmlstring = file_get_contents("http://applications.opap.gr/DrawsRestServices/kino/drawDate/21-12-2014.xml");

// converts $xmlstring to multidimensional array
$arrayMD = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($xmlstring)), true);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arrayMD);
echo "</pre>";

// converts multidimensional array to one-dimensional array
// in other words: "flattens" a multidimensional array
$array = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arrayMD));
foreach($array as $v) {
  echo $v . "<br>";
}
?>
```

The output would be as follows:

```
array(1) {
  ["draw"]=>
  array(157) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["drawNo"]=>
      string(6) "475781"
      ["drawTime"]=>
      string(25) "2014-12-21T09:00:00+02:00"
      ["result"]=>
      array(20) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "6"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "7"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "12"
        [3]=>
        string(2) "13"
        [4]=>
        string(2) "15"
        [5]=>
        string(2) "16"
...
```

Reference:

- [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)
- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (When second parameter is set to TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.)
- [JSON Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)
- (array) - cast to array, [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)
- [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/2510628)

Update:

To access some specific element of the multidimensional array:

```
$someVar = $arrayMD["draw"][0]["result"][7];
echo $someVar; // outputs: 12
```

Additionally, have a look at the [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function (assigns variables as if they were an array) or [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) (imports variables into the current symbol table from an array).

Or the easiest way is just to use several [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to output them, sum the numbers, select every fifth "result" value of every "draw" or anything else. (This depends on what are you going to do with those values next.)

Comment: Dmytro could u tell me how i can put all these [0]=>
        string(1) "6"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "7"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "12"
        [3]=>
        string(2) "13"
        [4]=>
        string(2) "15"
        [5]=>
        string(2) "16" into variables so i can use them?

Comment: echo $array['draw'][$k]['result'][$i] this is the answer thank you dmytro